# Visual Studio Formatting -- Change Method Color

Tags: visual-studio, formatting, methods, colors

The default appearance of a method for example, ".ToString()" is by default the color black.  I want to make it a different color to stand out but I do not see any options that reference this option specifically.

I remember one of former collegues showing me his VS IDE years ago and he had it setup this way but I cannot recall what he did.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in syntax highlighters use *lexical analysis*.  A lexer can classify identifiers, comments, literals, numbers, keywords.  The parts you find back in the Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors dialog.

Recognizing that an identifier is a method, property, field requires *parsing*.  Parsing generally only works well when you've got a well-formed program, you rarely have one while you are typing code.  So wasn't favored by Microsoft.  You can find alternatives in the [Visual Studio gallery](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=syntax%20highlighting&target=VS&sortBy=Relevance).

Comment: This is very well possible in Eclipse. I know it because I have changed the appearance for methods to be dark green and bold in Eclipse. Visual Studio does not seem to have this feature. Probably because the parser used is not as powerful as Eclipse's parser. I don't agree with your arguments that the code needs to be well-formed, because the parser also works when the code has errors.

Comment: Sadly it's true for VS, but IntelliJ IDEA works well distinguishing method and field. I don't know why Microsoft cannot make it.

Comment: Mono Develop has this :)

Comment: I know this is an old answer and doesn't really apply any more with Roslyn but I believe VSCode highlights methods via lexical analysis as well and does this, just checks to see if the identifier is followed by a bracket or not!

Answer (score 40):

In VS 2019 go to Tools - Options - Text Editor - C# - Advanced - Editor Color Scheme and change it to Visual Studio 2019. Method names are now colored and everything has little bit better colors.

Comment: After updating visual studio, this setting reverted to 2017 for some reason.  This answer helped me figure that out.

Comment: Same here, an update set it to 2017. Thank you very much!

Comment: And after you have set the styles to VS 2019, the method name style can be customized in  Tools -- Options -- Environment -- Fonts and Colors -- UserMembers-Methods.

Answer (score 24):

You can do this with an extension: **[SemanticColorizer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd89374f-892a-42d6-8207-da8fefa93fdf)** is what I use.

*Tools* -> *Extensions and Updates* -> *Online* -> Search for *SemanticColorizer*

It allows you to modify the colors of methods, static functions, constants, member variables, and just about anything else you can think of.

Answer (score 12):

To change the color of the Method Calls go to

> Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > User Members - Methods > Item foreground Color > Select desired color.

This will also work in Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 10):

For Visual Studio 2010

Tools > Options

Environment > Fonts and Colors

Change "User Types"

Comment: Work like a charm

Answer (score 9):

Go to Visual Studio "Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors" the menu shows a "Display Items" list, select "Identifiers"(out of which 'methods' is a member). Use the format controls to personalize the displaying of your chosen item. Unfortunately, variables, instances and namespaces are members of "Identifiers" so they will affected too.

If you are using Resharper then a more specific list of items is displayed.

Comment: To enable Resharper identifiers coloring, go to: **Code Inspection** -> **Settings** page and check the **Color Identifiers** checkbox

Answer (score 8):

For myself, I wrote a simple, lightweight "editor classifier extension" for **Visual Studio** based on the async **Roslyn APIs** to **Syntax Highlighting** user tags in **C#** and **Visual Basic** code.

It has **syntax highlighting** for:

- "**Events**"
- "**Fields**"
- "**Fields (Constant)**"
- "**Fields (Inside Enums)**"
- "**Local Variables**"
- "**Methods**"
- "**Methods (Extension)**"
- "**Methods (Static)**"
- "**Namespaces**"
- "**Parameters**"
- "**Properties**"

In the future, perhaps coming on the "**syntax highlighting**" for something else.

You can install this extension from the **Visual Studio Marketplace** by following the link below:

**Download: "[Enhanced Syntax Highlighting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting)".**

You can **change the syntax highlighting settings** by going to "**Tools**" > "**Options**" > "**Environment**" > "**Fonts and Colors**" > "**Text Editor**" and scrolling to properties starting with the prefix "**User Tags - ...**".

The **syntax highlighting** options for "**Classes**", "**Delegates**", "**Enums**", "**Interfaces**", "**Modules**", "**Structures**" and "**Type Parameters**" are just below, they have the prefix "**User Types - ...**" and are built-in default.

Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to "@Ian" said User Types. For me "User Members - Methods" worked.

1. Tools
2. Options
3. Enviromment
4. Fonts and Colors
5. In Display items: "**User Members - Methods**"
6. Change Item foreground

Answer (score 1):

Semantic Colorizer didn't work for me (VS 2019 Preview).

Enhanced Syntax Highlighting did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

**Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors** has an extensive list of things you can change both font face, font size, color, style, etc.

Also, Jeff Atwood had a great post a few years ago about [IDE font and colour schemes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/is-your-ide-hot-or-not.html) that you might find interesting.

Comment: Yeah I know about these options.  But which one specifically does the change I mentioned above?

Comment: There is none, as far as I know. At least without some 3rd party extension.

Answer (score -1):

In a previous version of visual studio (I think 2010) there was a plugin that allowed you to color code methods. I don't remember the name of it now as we have continued to progress forward in versions. The author did not keep up with the version updates of VS.

Update: VS10x allows you to color code methods in Visual Studio all the way through VS2015. A link to the authors Visual Studio Galleries page can be found here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2?SRC=VSIDE

I am currently using this in VS2013 successfully.