# How do I set different colors for local and global variables in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, themes

I've been using monodevelop for a while and was using the 'Monokai' theme. Its coloring was very detailed. As you can see in the screenshot the local and global variables have different colors. 
[image: Monodevelop colors]

Recently I've started using Visual Studio 2017 and can't seem to find a theme that uses different colors for local and global vars.

[image: Visual Studio colors]

I've tried going to `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and colors` and couldn't find any setting to individually adjust the text colors of locals and globals.
Even though I name these differently, the coloring makes debugging and code reading a bit more easier.

Does anyone know a way to give unique colors to local and global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a way to do this within Visual Studio.  There may be a 3rd party add-on/extension that may do this.

UPDATE:
Visual Studio 2019, via a software update, recently changed the granularity in which variables can be color 'coded'.  Please see [Alex's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562632/how-do-i-set-different-colors-for-local-and-global-variables-in-visual-studio/57617120#57617120) below for the now correct answer.

Comment: You maybe right. But I still hope someone can come up with a solution.

Comment: That's why most people will use an underscore as a prefix for a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, I do that too. But having different colors makes it a bit more easier to quickly identify them.

Comment: See Alex's answer, it is possible now in VS2019

Comment: Thank you @tscissors.  I've updated my 'answer' to tell future readers that Alex's answer is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is the default behavior now. VS 2019 and 2022 now color global and local vars/parameters differently by default.

Customized under `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors`.

For C# these are the items starting with `User Members -`.

Comment: Yeah not for C#. I had to install SemanticColorizer like Aj_ mentioned.

Comment: @jsirr13 I just edited the answer to show which fields apply to C#. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/57007495/825588

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I installed an extension called [SemanticColorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasReischuck.SemanticColorizer) and that did the trick. Still, if anyone has any other solutions, please post it here.

Comment: I wish that there were soemthing similar for C++